# $s_n =( \frac{1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}}{\log n}) \to 1$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

I know that the above limit is 1 from Wolfram but I had no proper way to prove. I attempted a proof and it is as follows:
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \dfrac{1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3}  + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{n}}{\log n} \right)= \dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{n} dn}{ \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \log n}.$$

Using L Hopital's rule $\left( \dfrac{\infty}{\infty} \text{ form} \right)$ and Leibnitz rule we get
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{n}}{\dfrac{1}{n}} = 1.$$ I think that this is not the best way to approach this problem and there must be a better way to prove/solve this problem.

Comment: Think about harmonic numbers (the numerator) and use asymptotics

Comment: Use comparision to an integral, for $f\searrow$ we have $\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\,dx\le f(n)\le\int_{n-1}^{n}f(x)\,dx$

Comment: Don't use L'Hôpital's rule, use [its cousin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Comment: The difference tends to the Euler Mascheroni constant , hence the quotient must tend to $1$.

Comment: @J.G. the denominator is not a sequence, how is stolz cesaro applicable?

Comment: @DatBoi You can define $b_n:=\ln n$ with no problem.

Comment: @J.G. ah i see!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \dfrac{1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3}  + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{n}}{\log n} \right)= \dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{n} dn}{ \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \log n}$$
makes absolutely no sense.  The numerator on the RHS $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{n} \, dn$$ is a fixed constant.  Moreover, your reuse of $n$ as the variable of integration is inappropriate.  Finally, the distribution of the limit into the numerator and denominator is also incorrect; e.g., $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \ne \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x}{\lim_{x \to 0} x} = \frac{0}{0}.$$

Instead, recall that for all $x \ge 1$, $$x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x ,$$ so that $$\frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \le \frac{1}{x-1}.$$  Then integrating this expression from $x = k$ to $x = k+1$ yields
$$\log \frac{k+1}{k} = \int_{x=k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{x} \, dx < \int_{x=k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \, dx \le \int_{x=k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{x-1} \, dx = \log \frac{k}{k-1}.$$  But the middle integral is simply $1/k$, since for all $x \in [k, k+1)$, $1/\lfloor x \rfloor = k$.  Therefore, we have established
$$\log (k+1) - \log k < \frac{1}{k} \le \log k - \log (k-1),$$ for positive integers $k > 1$, and for $k = 1$, obviously $1/k \le 1$.  Now summing from $k = 1$ to $n$ and observing the telescoping, we get

$$\log n \le \log (n+1) \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \le 1 + \log n.$$  This allows us to obtain a sufficiently tight bound by which the limit may be established through the squeeze theorem:

$$1 \le \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}}{\log n} \le \frac{1}{\log n} + 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is wrong in several ways. First, it's not true that $$1+\dots+\frac1n=\int_0^1\frac1n\,dn.$$That integral equals $+\infty$; in particular it's not a function of $n$ and certainly not a function with derivative $1/n$.

A correct proof: Arguing as in the integral test shows that $$1+\dots+\frac1n-\log n\to c.$$Now prove this:

> > If $A_n,B_n>0$, $A_n\to+\infty$ and $A_n-B_n$ is bounded then $A_n/B_n\to1$.